# Equation of a surface

Tags: vectors

[image]

Why is vector S called surface instead of the normal vector of the plane? What actually is S? Can S be in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 0):

Making some interpretations without having the full details... I think that you’re asked here is not to provide the *equation for the surface*, but the *equation for computing the algebraic area of the colored surface*. The orientation being given by the vector.

If that is correct, then the answer is *Only (a) is correct*.

Comment: Apart from perhaps the sign, why would the two cross products give different results?

Comment: @Henry I do agree that the only possible difference is the vector direction.